# Should I define list-style on <li> or <ul> too?

Tags: html, css

Is there a good reason to override CSS `list-style` on both `<ul>` and `<li>` or just `<li>`?

Comment: Note, my specific use case is to make a navigation list using left floated `<li>`s with no `list-style`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style), you'll see that property is intended to style "elements with `display: list-item`".

The property is inherited if not explicitly defined on the `<li>` elements, so you should stick to applying the style to only `<li>` elements.

Answer (score 3):

Per [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/list-style-type) you can define `list-style-type` on any element with `display:list-item`.

As far as I know, in modern browsers you can set any element to `display: list-item` so that - if you wanted to - you could correctly use the `list-style-type` property on any of them.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>12084892</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        div span {
            display:list-item; 
            list-style-type: disc; 
            list-style-position: inside;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<span>One</span>
<span>Two</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Trivia tidbit aside, what behavior are you looking to get? If you want different list items in the same list to have different bullets, then you'll need to define the `list-style-type` on the `li`s themselves. If you want all the `li`s within a given `ul` to have the same bullet, it's up to you. I typically define this on the `ul`, however. It is more intuitive to do it that way for me, personally.

Comment: Another answer below links to the list-style-type w3.org page where they give an example in which defining list-style-type on the li elements has possibly unintended consequences. They go on to say that the preferred way then is to define list-style-type on the containing lists instead of the list items. [Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#list-style).

Comment: thanks for the answer. Though your example is a little off topic as I was asking specifically about ul/li, I do appreciate the additional details of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same one, no. Just define it on whatever's convenient to you; `<li>`s will inherit the `<ul>`'s `list-style` unless explicitly overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance  transfer the '`list-style`' values from `ol` and `ul` elements to `li` elements.

so i think  you should  apply the style to only `li` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Even if list style is getting inherited from UL/OL, you should define css list-style to li only. And You can create different list styles with each other in one list. For example:

```
ul.test li {
list-style:disc;
margin:0 0 0 20px;
}
​ul li:first-child {
list-style:circle;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You should normally set `list-style` on `ul` and `ol` elements only, because this avoids unexpected and undesired problems caused by cascading rules. See [description of `list-style](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#list-style) in CSS 2.1 spec.

For example, `ol li { list-style: upper-roman; }` may look safe, but consider this:

```
<ol>
  <li>foo
  <ul>
    <li>bar
  </ul>
</ol>
```

Now the inner `li` element, with “bar” content, will have the list style applied to it, because it too matches the selector `ol li`. (It is true that using the selector `ol > li` would avoid this, but it has browser compatibility issues.)

Setting `ol { list-style: upper-roman; }` instead avoids the issue, since now the inner `li` does not match, and it inherits `list-style` from its parent, `ul` (which has a suitable setting in browser default style sheet).

However, you need to set `list-type` directly on an `li` if you want one particular list item be styled differently from other items in the same list. In such cases, you will normally use an id selector or other selector that matches that specific element only, not any inner `li` elements.